# Get data from dictionary inside an JSON-parsed Array

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary

I have an Array full with dictionaries,

```
(
    {
    "id_color" = 8;
    nombre = "Amarillo p\U00e1lido";
},
    {
    "id_color" = 9;
    nombre = "Amarillo p\U00e1lido/toffy claro";
},
    {
    "id_color" = 13;
    nombre = Azul;
},
    {
    "id_color" = 12;
    nombre = Magenta;
},
    {
    "id_color" = 18;
    nombre = Morado;
})
```

I can access the data of the dictionries doing this:

```
let coloresArray = jsonResult["colores"] as! NSArray
            let colorDict = coloresArray[0] as! NSDictionary
            print (colorDict["nombre"]!)
```

But is there a way to access the value of the keys doing something like this

```
jsonResult["colores"][0]["nombre"]
```

Thanks for the answer

Comment: Do not use `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` in Swift. Use Swift arrays and Swift dictionaries of the proper type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly cast the steps. Avoid force-casting and force-unwrapping when parsing JSON data.

The proper and safe way to get the data you want is:

```
if let colores = jsonResult["colores"] as? [[String:Any]], let nombre = colores[0]["nombre"] as? String {
    print(nombre)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a purely grammatical question, you can always nest expressions, even those with `as!` operators:

```
var s = ((jsonResult["colores"] as! NSArray)[0] as! NSDictionary)["nombre"] as! NSString
```

However, this is bad style and strategy for a number of reasons. At least, use native Swift types:

```
 var s = ((jsonResult["colores"] as! [Any])[0] as! [String: Any])["nombre"] as! String
```

But this will cause crashes if the unwrapping fails, so use chained Optionals:

```
 var s = ((jsonResult["colores"] as? [Any])?[0] as?[String: Any])?["nombre"] as? String // Now s is String?, be sure to treat as Optional
```

But you might as well make the type cast in one go: we want an Array of Dictionaries with String keys:

```
var s = (jsonResult["colores"] as? [[String: Any]])?[0]["nombre"] as? String
```

Or, probably you want to take other properties, so maybe:

```
if let colorObj = (jsonResult["colores"] as? [[String: Any]])?[0] {
    if let s = colorObj["nombre"] as String { ... }
    if let id = colorObj["id_color"] as Int { ... }
}
```

However, if this looks painful, it's because it is, and you may want to avail yourself of built-in translation from JSON to native Swift objects via the `Codable` interface:

https://medium.com/xcblog/painless-json-parsing-with-swift-codable-2c0beaeb21c1

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
struct struct_color : Decodable {
        let id_color: Int
        let nombre: String
    }

    private func get_data()
    {
        let url_request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://masterfood.000webhostapp.com/test/")!)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url_request)
        { (url_data, url_response, url_error) in
            if let error = url_error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                if let data = url_data {
                    do {
                        let colores = try JSONDecoder().decode([struct_color].self, from: data)
                        print("\n\n")
                        print(colores)
                        print("\n")
                        for color in colores
                        {
                            print("\(color.id_color) : \(color.nombre)")
                        }
                        print("\n\n")
                    } catch {
                        let err = error as NSError
                        print(err)
                    }
                }
            }

        }.resume()
    }




    /*


[ViewController.struct_color(id_color: 1, nombre: "amarillo"), 
         ViewController.struct_color(id_color: 2, nombre: "cafe"), 
         ViewController.struct_color(id_color: 3, nombre: "gris"), 
         ViewController.struct_color(id_color: 4, nombre: "rojo")]


1 : amarillo
2 : cafe
3 : gris
4 : rojo
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to decode the JSON into structs with the `Decodable` protocol, no type cast, no key/index subscription:

```
let jsonString = """
{"colores":[{"id_color":8,"nombre":"Amarillo pálido"},
{"id_color":9,"nombre":"Amarillo pálido/toffy claro"},
{"id_color":13,"nombre":"Azul"},
{"id_color":12,"nombre":"Magenta"},
{"id_color":18,"nombre":"Morado"}]}
"""

struct Root : Decodable {
    let colores : [Color]
}

struct Color : Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case idColor = "id_color", nombre}

    let nombre : String
    let idColor : Int
}


let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)

do {
    let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    for color in root.colores {
        print(color.nombre)
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```